# Eureka ebook reader is blocking all screenshots - how do I turn off this behavior?

Tags: windows-11, screenshot

Reposting similar question with better information. I have an ebook that is readable only through [Eureka](https://www.archimediaadvantage.com/copy-of-about), an ebook reader that I have only have seen used for actuarial study materials. Print screen and the snipping tool both result in completely black screens. Is there a way to turn this off? I want to keep some notes but do not want to write out entire pages. I am on Windows 11.

Edit with more info: I can find the PDF in file explorer, but trying to open with another PDF reader like Sumatra asks for a password.

Comment: @harrymc Purchased through actuarialbookstore.com which then leads to another login  which has a list of your digital purchases. From there you can download the installer for Eureka for the relevant platform. You can also find the installer [here](https://www.archimediaadvantage.com/copy-of-about). Note: the entire actuarial professional organization system is a racket and pull stuff like this all the time

Comment: Take photos & use OCR. Hopefully you have an iPhone with built-in OCR from pictures of text.

Comment: That's what I've resorted to (though with Android) but I'd like to grab more of the book and that's a pain. I might just get work to expense a used version for $140 

Comment: That's the whole point of DRM, though - you can't just help yourself to a copy.

Comment: @Tetsujin ya I know. And that's stupid. I paid over $200 for a book I can't keep and the license runs out in a few months. You'd understand my frustration more if you were an actuary. The SOA pulls this bs all the time

Comment: "If I were an actuary" You don't know just how funny that is, to me. I worked in life assurance for several years straight from school, failed accountancy 101 with I think the lowest score the college had ever seen. Left & went to be a musician instead. Never looked back ;)

Comment: A cheap screen capture card? Maybe also start a revolution.

Comment: Though I **do not recommend** breaking the law, there are tools to remove DRM. US$200 for short-term rental of an etext is reprehensible to me! You might enjoy reading Cory Doctorow's *unauthorized bread*, *sans* DRM, on this topic: https://craphound.com/content/download/

Comment: @Tetsujin I have no artistic talent sadly so I had to stick with math

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I'll check that out and continue to fight the power 

Comment: Whereas I can't add up a dartboard score without a calculator. Each to his/her/their own ;))

Comment: After your edit - perhaps one of these - https://superuser.com/questions/179064/how-to-remove-security-from-a-pdf-file

Comment: @Tetsujin thanks I'm still going through them but most won't work because I need a password to just open the file! This obscure ebook and ereader seems to have the most advanced DRM in the world lol

Comment: @drj3122 It is possible that they use Microsoft Information Protection https://deviceadvice.io/2021/11/01/block-screenshots-using-microsoft-information-protection/ In that case, use a screen capture card.

Comment: @Gantendo thanks for suggestion. After looking at various password crackers, all of them just ask for the password lol, so I think screencap is my best option